# Get properties with attribute

Tags: c#

I am trying to solve a problem how to get a required properties from the class. I can use function like `GetPropertiesForSerialization`, but I would like to use `Attributes`. My idea is that some class properties will have attribute

```
class C{
  [MyAttribute(1,picture)]
  private string picture = "my.jpg";
  [MyAttribute(2,Name)]
  public string Name= "myName";
}
```

And now I from other class I would like to get the attributes

```
private void PrintAttributes(){
  //Get list or other container with attibutes
  var c = new C();
  foreach( var item in C.GetMyAttributes()){
    Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
}
```

I know how to get attributes of function etc. but don't know how to get all this attribues without knowing the property name and the protection (public/private).

Comment: Are you trying to get all the property names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the properties using reflection `myObject.GetType().GetProperties()` , and then check each one for your attribute.

Comment: Ok, I will try this 'brutal force'.

Comment: if you are serilizing lots of objects of the same type, you can just do it once per type and cache the results.

Comment: I try it and `item.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(MyAttribute), true);` but nothing founded. The class implements interface and stored in `ÌnterfaceI class; class.GetType...`. But no property with attribute found

Comment: Sorry my misstake ... just need GetProperties and GetField ;)